# 2005 Honda Pilot Not Starting

Tags: honda

I was recently given an 05 Honda Pilot. 221,000 miles on it. I can’t afford to buy anything for else at the moment or spend a lot of money on a repair. It was running great until he other day. Pulled out of the driveway from a job site and it was running fine and when I hit 3000 rpm, it acted like it died and the VTM 4, “!”, Check Engine, and VSA light came on. From that point it seemed to be in limp mode because it would not let me get above 3000 rpm. I pulled into a gas station and it was idling terrible and it died. So I checked under the hoods to make sure nothing obvious was wrong. Tried to start it back up and it started and ran rough for al of 15 seconds and then died and now I cannot get it to restart again. I have verified that it is getting spark, and fuel. Timing belt and tensioner was replaced 15,000 miles ago at the most by a very trusted source before I got the car. Any help?? I was curious as to whether or not a failed cam/crank sensor could affect the sequence/timing of injector pulse or ignition??

Comment: Get a OBD2 code reader and read the codes in the computer.

Comment: I rented one yesterday, and no codes came up in the system. Only ABS codes were present but they were all related to power failure or low voltage, assuming they were there because I nearly ran the battery completely dead trying to start it.

Comment: How did you verify spark and fuel delivery?

Comment: I pulled a coil loose for the spark and I pulled the fuel line loose at the injector rail

Comment: Did you verify proper fuel pressure?

Comment: I did not have a fuel pressure tester so no.